# How can I observe uploadProgress while Uploading Multipart Form Data?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have to upload both image and userId to server, so I use `Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:to:encodingCompletion:)` to upload.

But there is no way to observe the progress of uploading.

Should I use other method instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with this:

```
Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        //your implementation 
    },
    to: "http://example.com",
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
            }
            upload.uploadProgress { progress in

                print(progress.fractionCompleted)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: You are welcome! Happy to help ;)